# Java how not to print string from for loop? (ARRAY)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a homework question where I need to get user input for names and marks into two arrays. Then I ask the user for a mark and it tells them which name obtained the mark. If no one got the mark, it says "Mark can't be found".

I have a problem in the last part where it goes through the for loop and if a name in the list got the mark, it prints out "Mark can't be found" for all the other spots in the array who's name did not match the mark. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
double [] mark = new double[4];
String [] name = new String[4];

for (int count=0; count<name.length; count++) {
  System.out.println("Enter name #" + (count+1) + ":");
  name[count] = sc.nextLine();
  sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter mark #" + (count+1) + ":");
  mark[count] = sc.nextDouble();
  sc.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Enter a mark: ");
double secondmark = sc.nextDouble();
for (int count=0; count<name.length; count++) {
  if (secondmark==mark[count]) {
    System.out.println((name[count])+ " got the mark.");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Mark can't be found");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do it in several steps. Your loop could just find the index of the person who got the mark, and then AFTER the loop have a if that display the proper message.

Comment: You could also `break;` out of the for loop if you found the mark.

Comment: In general, if you think something happening shouldn't be, or something's happening that isn't, check the blocks that the problematic statement is in. In this case, the `System.out.println` in the `else` block inside the `for` loop. Statements inside loops tend to get executed a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the following section of code:

```
for (int count=0; count<name.length; count++) {
   if (secondmark==mark[count]) {
     System.out.println((name[count])+ " got the mark.");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Mark can't be found");
    }
}
```

If you see, for every value, it checks if it has a mark. If not, it prints Mark cannot be found, which is why your seeing all those values. What you need to do instead is add a boolean to store whether it was found or not, and then report if it cannot be found after the loop. For instance:

```
boolean foundMark = false;
for (int count=0; count<name.length; count++) {
   if (secondmark==mark[count]) {
     System.out.println((name[count])+ " got the mark.");
     foundMark = true;
   }           
}

if(foundMark == false){
   System.out.println("Mark can't be found");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to put the *"Mark can't be found"* outside the loop, we can use a boolean variable to help us determine when it's appropriate to display the message.

```
boolean flag = false;
for (int count = 0; count < name.length; count++) {
     if (secondmark == mark[count]) {
         System.out.println((name[count])+ " got the mark.");
         flag = true;
         break;
     } 
}

if(!flag) System.out.println("Mark can't be found");
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a flag if the mark was found. Only print that it wasn't found after the for loop iterates through each name.

```
boolean markFound = false;
for (int count=0; count<name.length; count++)
{
  if (secondmark==mark[count]
  {
    markFound = true;
    System.out.println((name[count])+ " got the mark.");
  }
}

if (markFound == false)
{
    System.out.println("Mark can't be found");
}
```